# Ghost : how to get all scheduled posts

Tags: ghost

we can now schedule posts in Ghost ... but is it possible to get all scheduled posts for display ?

```
{{#get "posts" filter="tag:journal" limit="all" include="author" order="published_at desc"}}
```

will give only published posts ... and there is no scheduled_at field

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think so because I do not think the api returns any data that isn't a published post. So, your `limit=all` is only getting all published posts, not all draft/scheduled or whatever, so don't think there is any way to get this info via the api.